# awk sep data extracting lines after certain variable

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a large file that has some regular pattern

```
       snaps1:          Counter:             4966
        Opens:          Counter:           357283

     Instance:     s.1.aps.userDatabase.mount275668.attributes


       snaps1:          Counter:             0
        Opens:          Counter:           357283

     Instance:     s.1.aps.userDatabase.test.attributes
```

These line are repeated among other lines above and below.
I need to print the snaps1 line and also get the instance: line
So I need to search for snaps1 but only if counter is greater than 0 and then print snaps1 line and also the instance line.

Sorry have no clue on how to do this? 
Can you help?

So from the lines above I should see this output

```
snaps1:          Counter:             4966
Instance:        s.1.aps.userDatabase.mount275668.attributes
```

Appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: Thank u as well and ur detail explaintion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '/snaps1/{s=$0; c=$NF} /Instance/ && c{print s ORS $0}' file
       snaps1:          Counter:             4966
     Instance:     s.1.aps.userDatabase.mount275668.attributes
```

Comment: Hi I tried your command as well - still getting awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
I also tried cat the file and pip the command same error

Comment: That error message **only** comes from old, broken awk which unfortunately is the default awk on Solaris. If you are on Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk (or less functional and non-POSIX but nawk works OK for most things too). On all systems, try to get/use GNU awk if in any way possible.

Comment: Hi thx for the quick reply - I did try the /usr/xpg4/bin/awk  and I ran it against my file and no result came at all.. I know there are lines with that

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
awk '/snaps1/ && $NF>0{print;f=1}f&&/Instance/{print;f=0}' file
```

To avoid blanks at the *beginning* of the line:

```
awk '/snaps1/ && $NF>0{gsub(/^ */,"");print;f=1}
     f&&/Instance/    {gsub(/^ */,"");print;f=0}'  file
```

**Results**

```
snaps1:          Counter:             4966
Instance:     s.1.aps.userDatabase.mount275668.attributes
```

**Explanation**

`/snaps1/ && $NF>0 {gsub(/^ */,"");print;f=1}` is used to set `f` *flag* when `snaps1` pattern is found **and** the last field `NF` must be greater than one also deletes unwanted spaces and print current line.

**NOTE** `/snaps1/ && $NF` it's an equivalent expression, the reason: *any* numeric value except zero is *true* for `awk`.

`f&&/Instance/ {gsub(/^ */,"");print;f=0}` if `f` flag is `True` (`1`) **and** `Instance` pattern is found, print the current line (deleting not wanted spaces) an set the flag back to false.

Comment: Hi and thx I tried ur command but getting syntax error?  awk '/snaps1/{s=$0; c=$NF} /Instance/ && c{print s ORS $0}' adsmobout.21.37.59  awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: Sorry fr late / delay response-- You command works as well. My apologies I'am trying to understand how it work....